# Как показать диалог "To Save File"?

Tags: .net, c++-cli

Чтоб при нажатии вылезало окно с сохранением файла (textBox). Я много прочитал, но так и не понял.

Answer (score 1):

Кидаешь на форму **SaveFileDialog** из панели элементов или создаешь указатель на него:

```
   SaveFileDialog ^saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
```

Потом например в событии по нажатию на кнопку:

```
   saveFileDialog1->Filter = "Text Files|*.txt";   // чтобы можно было сохранить только с разрешением txt (если не нужно - убери)
   saveFileDialog1->FilterIndex = 2 ;
   saveFileDialog1->RestoreDirectory = true ;
   if(saveFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK) //проверка, если закрыто по нажатию кнопки ОК
    {        
       IO::File::WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1->FileName,textBox1->Text);
    }
```

Собственно ваш файл готов.

Answer (score 0):

[Практическое руководство. Сохранение файлов с помощью компонента SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/sfezx97z.aspx)

```
SaveFileDialog ^sfd = new SaveFileDialog();

sfd->Title = "Сохранить файл";
sfd->ShowDialog();
if(sfd->FileName != "") {
    StreamWriter^ sw = gcnew StreamWriter(filename);

    sw->Write(tb->Text());
    sw->Close();        
}
```

Comment: Спосибо А как зделать что бы оно сохраняло Текст Из TextBox

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: sw: необъявленный идентификатор синтаксическая ошибка: идентификатор "StreamWriter"
sw: необъявленный идентификатор
 выражение слева от "->Write" должно указывать на тип класса, структуры или объединения либо на универсальный тип
: error C2065: tb: необъявленный идентификатор
 error C2227: выражение слева от "->Text" должно указывать на тип класса, структуры или объединения либо на универсальный тип
1>          тип: 'unknown-type'
 sw: необъявленный идентификатор
выражение слева от "->Close" должно указывать на тип класса, структуры или объединения либо на универсальный тип