# Как текст сохранить в файл?

Tags: c++-cli

Что необходимо дописать, чтобы сохранить из textBox->Text текст в файл:

```
     IO::Stream^ myStream;
    SaveFileDialog^ saveFileDialog1 = gcnew SaveFileDialog;
    saveFileDialog1->Filter = "Sudoky файлы (*.sdk)|*.sdk|Все файлы (*.*)|*.*";
    saveFileDialog1->FilterIndex = 1;
    saveFileDialog1->RestoreDirectory = true;
    if ( saveFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK 
     && saveFileDialog1->FileName->Length > 0)          {
        if ( (myStream = saveFileDialog1->OpenFile()) != nullptr ){



            myStream->Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: возможно поможет код на C#: http://www.cyberforum.ru/windows-forms/thread598880.html

Comment: Вот и переходите на C#. Забудьте о C++/CLI как о кошмарном сне.

Comment: по учебе еще надо помучаться на С++

Answer (score 1):

нашел решение благодаря: [Как показать диалог "To Save File"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/78887/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-to-save-file)

```
private: System::Void saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
            SaveFileDialog^ saveFileDialog1 = gcnew SaveFileDialog;
            saveFileDialog1->Filter = "Sudoky файлы (*.sdk)|*.sdk|Все файлы (*.*)|*.*";
            saveFileDialog1->FilterIndex = 1;
            saveFileDialog1->RestoreDirectory = true;
            if ( saveFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK 
             && saveFileDialog1->FileName->Length > 0)          {
                    IO::File::WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1->FileName,textBox00->Text);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Уберите из кода строку `if` - она здесь бессмысленна. Оставьте только `File::WriteAllText`. И переменную `myStream` можно убрать.

Comment: а что этот if означает ?

Comment: @spy686: Этот if в вашем ответе, так что вопрос о том, что он значит, к вам.

Comment: это было взято из другого места и для чего оно не известно. @VladD Ваш комментарий рассматриваю как просто ... и могу пожелать Вам только удачи. Если дельного сказать нечего, лучше молчать.

Comment: @spy686: Если вы пишете решение, отвечаете за него вы и только вы. При этом вы, разумеется, должны понимать, что оно делает и как.

Comment: (myStream = saveFileDialog1->OpenFile()) != nullptr ) Похоже что проверка, на случай, если указан пустой файл